# ADB - dial a number by its contact name

Tags: android, adb

we can open contact list in phone using following command:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW content://contacts/people/
```

for a particular contact ID to open

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW content://contacts/people/1
```

`1` at  the end is the contact id of the contact

we can call a defined number using below command:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:+XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Can we select A predefined contact in contact list and make a call?
Like I already have Test_1 contact in my phone I want to call it. How to write command for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `adb shell` command to look up the phone number by contact's name in the latest Android version is:

```
content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/data --where 'mimetype="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2" and display_name="<name>"' --projection data4 | cut -d= -f2
```

You can easily combine it with your dialing command:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:$(content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/data --where 'mimetype="vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2" and display_name="Test_1"' --projection data4 | cut -d= -f2)
```

You have not mentioned your host PC operating system - so it's up to you to figure out proper escaping you would need to run this command from your PC

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no direct way you can call contact from phone book by name.
This is way you could be able to do it by custom app that you will be called from adb shell

Example app, please **grant permission manually** as I didn't implement Permission handling and multiple number lookup

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="call.phonebook">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="call.phonebook.BY_NAME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 100;
    private String contactNumber;
    private Uri data, uriContact;
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        intent = getIntent();
        data = getIntent().getData();

        if (data != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
            makeCall();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void makeCall() {
        data = intent.getData();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (data != null && action != null) {
            String name = data.getSchemeSpecificPart();
            contactNumber = retrieveContactNumber(name);
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contactNumber));
            // TODO handle permissions
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            startActivity(callIntent);
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
    private String retrieveContactNumber(String name) {
        String contactNumber = null;
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + name + "'", null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
            // TODO handle multiple numbers
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            }
            phones.close();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return  contactNumber;
    }
}
```

Here is call for terminal

```
adb shell am start 
-n "call.phonebook/call.phonebook.MainActivity" 
-a  call.phonebook.BY_NAME -d name:Test
```

**Test** is in my case Contact saved in Phonebook

Let me know if this will work for you